# Why I get NullPointer in transaction manager when I pass there a connection pool?

Tags: java, database, servlets, database-connection

working in with servlets and jdbc came across a problem. I get a NullPointer in my transaction manager, and I can not figure out why. I configure the connection pool using BasicDataSource, then I try to get the connection using the DataSource, but I get the NPE. I can not understand where I was wrong. And what is the problem? I will be grateful for the help!

```
public class TransactionManager {
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public TransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public <T> T doInTransaction(TransactionOperation<T> operation) {
        T result = null;

        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();  // here i got NPE
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);

            result = operation.operation(connection);

            connection.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            try {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.rollback();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

MyConnectionPool class:

```
public final class ConnectionPool {

    private ConnectionPool(){

    }

    public static BasicDataSource getPoolConnection() {

        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop_db");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        dataSource.setConnectionProperties("useSSL=false");
        return dataSource;
    }
```

My ConyextListener class:

```
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ContextListener.class);

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = ConnectionPool.getPoolConnection();
        UserService userService = new UserServiceImpl(dataSource);

        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("userService", userService);

        ServletContext servletContext = event.getServletContext();
        initLog4J(servletContext);
    }
```

Here i use my transaction manager:

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private TransactionManager transactionManager;

    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public UserServiceImpl(BasicDataSource dataSource) {
        userDAO = new UserDAOImpl();
        transactionManager = new TransactionManager(dataSource);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isExistUser(String login) {
        return transactionManager.doInTransaction( // here is my program to move to the transaction manager
                connection ->
                        userDAO.isExistUser(login, connection)
        );
    }
```

Exception stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [servlet.RegistrationServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at service.impl.UserServiceImpl.isExistUser(UserServiceImpl.java:33)
    at servlet.RegistrationServlet.doPost(RegistrationServlet.java:52)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

RegistrationServlet:

```
@WebServlet("/registration")
public class RegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(RegistrationServlet.class);

    private long startTime;

    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        userService = (UserService) getServletContext().getAttribute("userService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        httpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher(ConstantApp.JSPPages.REGISTRATION_PAGE).forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RegistrationInfo registrationInfo = new RegistrationInfoImpl(request);
        Map<String, String> validationError = Validation.validate(registrationInfo);
        CaptchaValidate captchaValidate = new CaptchaValidate(request);

        String contextType = getServletContext().getInitParameter(ConstantApp.ContextType.CONTEXT_TYPE);
        String imageName = getServletContext().getInitParameter(ConstantApp.ContextType.CONTEXT_AVATAR_PATH);
        boolean isValidateCaptcha = captchaValidate.validateCaptcha(contextType);
        boolean isValidTime = RegistrationTimer.isValidRegistrationTime(startTime, Integer.parseInt(getServletContext().getInitParameter(ConstantApp.ContextType.CONTEXT_REGISTRATION_TIME)));

        LOG.debug("Validation error map: " + validationError.entrySet());
        if (validationError.isEmpty() && !userService.isExistUser(registrationInfo.getLogin()) && isValidateCaptcha && isValidTime) {////// here i move to UserServiceImpl I do not get inside the conditions
            userService.registrationUser(new User(registrationInfo.getLogin(), registrationInfo.getFirstName(), registrationInfo.getLastName(), registrationInfo.getEmail(), registrationInfo.getPassword(), imageName, "client"));
            request.getSession().setAttribute(ConstantApp.SessionUserAttribute.SESSION_LOGIN, registrationInfo.getLogin());
            request.getRequestDispatcher(ConstantApp.JSPPages.INDEX_PAGE).forward(request, response);
        }
```

Comment: How could we know: you didn't post the exception stack trace, and we have no idea how you're using the TransactionManager.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed.

Comment: Now show us the code of RegistrationServlet

Comment: I added, but there's nothing special)

Comment: I can't find the problem in the code you posted. Try making the fields final, and see if you don't have any method trying to reset the fields to null. Run the code using the debugger, and see where the dataSource suddenly becomes null.